# Get list of instances, Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I need to get list of instances. I did so to do this:

```
def availableCafee = Cafee.list()
```

But now, my task is complicated. It requires if certain field in instance doesn't have an empty string value, other fields of the instance must be found via some controller and the other instance by this string value. Domain class is below.

If `apiInit` is empty, the instance added to list how in example above, if `apiInit` isn't empty, it assumed other fields wasn't initialized, so getting other fields requires via controller, which I've done and the other instance.So external API work is emulate. How to change example above to do this?

```
class Cafee {

    String cafeeName = ""
    int totalReservationPlaces = 0
    double placeCost = 0
    String currencyType = ""
    boolean isReservationAvailable = false
    boolean reservationTimeLimit = false
    boolean reservationDateLimit = false
    int totalPlaces = 0
    LocalTime startTimeLimit = new LocalTime()
    LocalTime endTimeLimit = new LocalTime()
    Date startDateLimit = new Date()
    Date endDateLimit = new Date()
    String region = ""
    String city = ""
    String apiInit = "" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to say is that a nullable object is causing the object not to be saved.

The solution is quite simple:

```
static constraints = {
        apiInit nullable: true
}
```

Have a read here: [rejected-value-null](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-2-3-4-rejected-value-null-td4653121.html)

So ideally set all those objects that are could be nullable should be set 
[ChatUser.groovy](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/domain/grails/plugin/wschat/ChatUser.groovy)

you can also set the defaultValue of an object in the mapping:

[MailingListBase.groovy](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/mailinglist/blob/master/grails-app/domain/grails/plugin/mailinglist/core/MailingListBase.groovy)

Please note if it is an already generated Database table any attempt now to set to nullable after it has been previously created will not work. you will either have to set this manually or drop it and let it regenerate..